# C libraries for socat Linux

Tags: linux, socat

I want to establish a connection between my linux pc (ubuntu 12.04) and a tty-device. I want to implement it in C and I am searching for libraries for socat. But I couldn't find any.

Do somebody know, where I can find some?

Thanks a lot,

Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find socat libraries because there are none. socat is implemented as a monolithic executable (it does link to the standard system libraries though). You can download [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) sources and copy-paste required functionality.